# Equivalent to Windows' "Disk Space Fan"?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, disk-usage

I used [this program](http://www.diskspacefan.com/screenshots.html) a fair bit back in Windows.

[image: screenshot of interactive interface graphical user interface gui... interactive!]

What's something vaguely equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several disk space analyzers in the Ubuntu repositories. Try several to see which you prefer. If you use Unity or GNOME, you'll probably want Baobab, or the others if you use KDE, because the programs' shortcuts will launch the corresponding desktop environment's file manager.

## Baobab

A GNOME program. I think Baobab is installed by default.

[image: baobab]

## Filelight

A KDE program.

[image: filelight]

## k4dirstat

Another KDE disk space analyzer. It displays as blocks instead of circles, which can help visualize the usage of deep directory hierarchies.

[image: k4dirstat]

Comment: Thanks! Filelight was most similar to "Disk Space Fan" (didn't try Baobab cuz Kubuntu-ing), but after playing with k4dirstat, I think I actually like that format even better. ^^

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking about disk usage analyzer which is already installed in your Ubuntu. [image]